# Why is the inflection of supellex so weird?

Tags: etymology, morphology

The noun **supellex** takes the stem **supellectil-** in declined forms. The **-il-** part seems related to the suffix **-ilis** as in **fragilis**, but it disappears in the nom. sg. form.

(By the way, the expected nom. sg. form **supellectilis** is also attested.)

According to Wiktionary, it comes from an unattested verb ***superlegere**. It reminds me of another noun **supplex**, which comes from the verb **supplicare** but without **-il-** in its declined forms.

How did this happen? Are there any similar examples for abnormal declension patterns?

Comment: I think it's clear that the oblique forms are suppletive, but the question of why still remains. However, that might not be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to just be suppletion.

The nominative and vocative continue supellex, *supellectis whilst all the other forms continue the extended supellectilis, supellectilis.